# How can I subtract a list from a list for its value inside the list?

Tags: python, list, math, computer-science

So I want to be able to subtract a list to another list.

For example, if I had two lists:

```
x = [0,8,10]
y = [1,7,9]
```

I would like to be able to basically `subtract y[i] - x[i]` using a FOR LOOP.

So ultimately, inside the loop, it would go 1-0, 7-8, 9-10, and so on if the list is longer.

Additionally, would there be any way to check if all or only one of the differences are equal to each other?

Thank you.

Comment: use `zip`......

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import operator
x = [0,8,10]
y = [1,7,9]
ans = list(map(operator.sub, y, x))
print(ans)
```

Output :

```
[1, -1, -1]
```